# Display bibliographies as section and subsections in report documentclass

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sectioning, chapters, nesting

I am trying to add the 2 bibliographies within the same chapter and each one is spanning certain sub-bibliographies. However using the **report** documentclass each bibliography is displayed as a chapter on its own.

So how can I let the bibliographies with `heading=bibnumbered` be displayed as sections and the ones with `heading=subbibnumbered` as subsections using the **report** documentclass?

**MWE**:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{E1, title = {Spanish Source 1}, author = {Placeholder}, keywords = {es}}
@online{E2, title = {Spanish Source 2}, author = {Placeholder}, keywords = {es}}
@book{G1, title = {German Source 1}, author = {Placeholder}, keywords = {de}}
@online{G2, title = {German Source 2}, author = {Placeholder}, keywords = {de}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Main}
\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum

\nocite{*}

\chapter{Bibliography}
\printbibheading[title={Spanish Sources}, heading=bibnumbered]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered, type=book, keyword={es}, title={Books}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered, nottype=legislation, nottype=book, keyword={es}, title={Articles}]


\printbibheading[title={German Sources}, heading=bibnumbered]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered, type=book, keyword={de}, title={Books}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered, nottype=legislation, nottype=book, keyword={de}, title={Articles}]

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC of MWE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new bibheading to create a subsection.

```
\defbibheading{subsubbibnumbered}[\refname]{% 
    \subsection{#1}}
```

and use `heading=subsubbibnumbered,`

(Use `heading=subbibnumbered` when you want a section.)

[image: a]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
    @book{E1, title = {Spanish Source 1}, author = {Placeholder}, keywords = {es}}
    @online{E2, title = {Spanish Source 2}, author = {Placeholder}, keywords = {es}}
    @book{G1, title = {German Source 1}, author = {Placeholder}, keywords = {de}}
    @online{G2, title = {German Source 2}, author = {Placeholder}, keywords = {de}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\defbibheading{subsubbibnumbered}[\refname]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \subsection{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Main}
    \section{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \chapter{Bibliography}
    \printbibheading[title={Spanish Sources}, heading=subbibnumbered]% section level <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subsubbibnumbered, type=book, keyword={es}, title={Books}]% subsection level <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \printbibliography[heading=subsubbibnumbered, nottype=legislation, nottype=book, keyword={es}, title={Articles}]
    
    
    \printbibheading[title={German Sources}, heading=subbibnumbered]
    \printbibliography[heading=subsubbibnumbered, type=book, keyword={de}, title={Books}]
    \printbibliography[heading=subsubbibnumbered, nottype=legislation, nottype=book, keyword={de}, title={Articles}]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: b]